# Change the permalinks structure

Tags: permalinks, pages, 404-error

I have decided my structure of permalinks from /?p=125 to /sample-page. I have tried some methods, but anyone works. I have changed the structure in settings/permalinks and I have tried with some plugin in order to get a redirecction, however I have not get anything. I don`t know what to do, because I get 404 error when I open any of my pages.
I would like to know how to solve this problem, and if it has any relation with my server.

Comment: Does your server meet [the requirements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) for pretty permalinks? ask your host if you are unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save permalink settings, is there the following notification at the bottom of page?

> If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically,
>   but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in
>   your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select
>   all.

I'm asking because the behaviour you described may be caused by non-existing or non-writable .htaccess file in your WordPress root.

If you have a shell access to the server environment (or you work locally), you can create this file and add writing permissions:

```
cd your_wp_directory
touch .htaccess
chmod a+w .htaccess
```

After that, save permalink settings again.

Comment: I have tried, but my hosting can`t let me use the console..However, the notification that you said did not appear at the bottom of page